# saml 2.0 identity provider AWS IAM could not parse metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, saml-2.0, adfs, idp

I have set up AD DS, AD FS, with a self signed cert exported. I have obtained the metadata file from the link :

```
https://my1.example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
```

However, when I try to load this to create an Identity Provider to be used for creating an SAML2.0 IAM Role,

it states this error :

We encountered the following errors while processing your request:
Could not parse metadata

can you please help? what is it that needs to be changed in the ADFS Federation Metadata xml content / file?

Answer (score 0):

My sincere apologies. Actually I had copy/pasted content of the /Federation/...xml,
whereas it actually downloads an xml file. Now open it in notepad, copy-paste it to a file where AWS Console is up to create idP.

Comment: Please be aware that the FederationMetadata from ADFS does include much more descriptors but the IDPSSODescriptor. You may only extract this descriptor as otherwise your SP configuration may be 'polluted' with unneeded information. (depends upon which SP implementation is being used)